# Using regex to capture phone numbers with spaces inserted at differing points

Tags: regex

I want to be able to extract a complete phone number from text, irrespective of how many spaces interrupt the number.

For example in the passage:

```
I think Emily was her name, and that her number was either 0421032614 or 0423 032 615 or 04321 98 564
```

I would like to extract:

```
0421032614
0423032615
0432198564
```

I can extract the first two using

```
(\d{4}[\s]?)(\d{3}[\s]?)+
```

But this is contingent on me knowing ahead of time how the ten numbers will be grouped (i.e. where the spaces will be). Is there any way to capture the ten numbers with a more flexible pattern?

Comment: Try to do it in  2 steps: 1) extract the 10 digit chunks with any amount of spaces in between with [`\d(?:\s*\d){9}`](https://regex101.com/r/rF6w3H/1) (or even a more precise `\b\d(?:\s*\d){9}\b`), and then 2) remove the whitespaces.

Comment: Consider each digit a group with optional whitespace between them, exactly like your groups, but just a single digit. You can also decide what to do with longer or shorter numbers (911 anybody?) and international numbers -- mine starts with +49.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribizew. I am quite new to Regex. Can you explain the function of the `?` and the `:` in the capturing group `(?:\s*\d)`?

Comment: It is not a capturing group, it is a non-capturing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove all white space then run a for loop and iterate through the groups:

```
    public static void main (String [] args){
    String reg = "(\\d{10})";
    String word = " think Emily was her name, and that her number was either 0421032614 or 0423 032 615 or 04321 98 564";

    word = word.replaceAll("\\s+",""); // replace all the whitespace with nothing

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(reg);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(word);

    while (mat.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= mat.groupCount(); i++) {
             System.out.println(mat.group(i));
        }
    } 

}
```

output is

```
0421032614
0423032615
0432198564
```